# What datatype to use?

Tags: c#, types

I need a collection that

- contains a set of objects linked to a double.
- The sequence of these pairs should be arbitrary set by me (based on an int I get from the database) and be static throughout the lifecycle.
- The number of entries will be small (0 ~ 20) but varying.
- The collection should be itteratable.
- I don't have to search the collection for anything.
- The double will be changed after intialization of the collection.
- I would like to work with existing datatypes (no new classes) since it will be used in my asp.net mvc controllers, views and services and I don't want them to all to have a dependency on a library just for this stupid holder class.

I thought

```
IDictionary<int, KeyvaluePair<TheType, double>>
```

would do the trick, but then I can't set the double after init.

**--Edit--**
I found out that the classes generated by the linq 2 sql visual studio thingy are actually partial classes so you can add to them whatever you want. I solved my question by adding a double field to the partial class.
Thanks all for the answers you came up with.

Comment: What do you mean by "linked to" a double?

Comment: The double is calculated depending on the fields of the object. Since I cannot add a method or field to the object itself I want to do it this way.

Comment: It seems to me like you might you want to subclass (extend) the object? Would be a lot more OO, the pattern names would be Proxy or Decorator.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you may just want an equivalent of `KeyValuePair`, but mutable. Given that you're only using it as a pair of values rather than a key-value pair, you could just do:

```
public class MutablePair<TFirst, TSecond>
{
    public TFirst First { get; set; }
    public TSecond Second { get; set; }

    public MutablePair()
    {
    }

    public MutablePair(TFirst first, TSecond second)
    {
        First = first;
        Second = second;
    }
}
```

This doesn't override GetHashCode or Equals, because you're not actually using those (as it's in a value position).

Comment: Your solution is correct, but my requirements weren't complete. Updated them. Could you have a look?

Comment: Constructors can not be generic. Of course I am pretty sure that you know that, but I commented anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct MyPair
{
    public object TheType;
    public double Value;
}

MyPair[] MyColleccyion = new MyPair[20];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, KeyValuePair is immutable (which is a good thing), so you'll have to replace the entire value of KeyValuePair, not just the part of it:

```
yourDict[10] = new KeyValuePair<TheType, Double>(yourDict[10].Key, newValue);
```

... or think like [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet). Gah. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
public class ListThing<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    public double DoubleThing { get; set; }

    public ListThing(double value)
    {
        DoubleThing = value;
    }
}
```